# Is there a way to determine the correct order of Okay / Cancel buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, joptionpane

We have a Swing application with a lot of input dialogs featuring okay and cancel buttons.

I've noticed that in JOptionPane the order of the okay and cancel buttons changes depending on platform. On Windows it's okay/cancel and on Unix it's cancel/okay.

Where we've added our own okay and cancel buttons I'd like the order of them to match the order they show in JOptionPane for consistency.

I was wondering if there's a way to interrogate the UIManager to find out what the correct order should be for the current look and feel or platform.

Thanks in advance.
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of the buttons in a JOptionPane is controlled by

```
boolean isYesLast = UIManager.getDefaults().getBoolean("OptionPane.isYesLast");
```

If `isYesLast` is true then the button order is reversed (e.g. yes/no/cancel -> cancel/no/yes)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Comment: NB: Returns incorrect result with [`AquaOptionPaneUI`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/laf/AquaOptionPaneUI.java).

Comment: @trashgod: interesting. AquaOptionPaneUI uses an own Layout to arrange the button area and bypasses the mechanisms defined by BaseOptionPaneUI.

Comment: I'm not getting the results I expected...

  `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`
  `Boolean isYesLast = (Boolean) UIManager.get("OptionPane.isYesLast");`
  `System.out.println(isYesLast);`
  `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "are you sure?");`
  `isYesLast = (Boolean) UIManager.get("OptionPane.isYesLast");`
  `System.out.println(isYesLast);`

I was expecting to see null for the first result, but I'm also seeing null for the second. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Wero,

com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel

Thanks
Matt

Comment: NB get same result if using getCrossPlatformLookAndFeel(): javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel ~Matt

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: But how to set the order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Object[] options = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Click OK to continue", "Warning",
JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
null, options, options[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to use the system look and feel, or allow the user to specify the look and feel. I just want to find out the correct order the buttons should be added based on whatever LAF is being used.

Comment: plz see editted answer. See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, only not the way you would expect it.
You have to design your own OptionPane class. And you have to extend from the JOptionPane. This way you can design where your buttons are going to be placed.
I would personally recommend to search for an other sollution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As per wero's answer above, this is the way to do it:

Boolean isYesLast = (Boolean)UIManager.get("OptionPane.isYesLast");